# Order of interrupt operations as handler ends

Tags: handler, exit, restore, interrupt

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I am working on an operating systems assignment and I can't seem to find any useful information for my problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

In what order should the following operations be done by an interrupt handler as the handler
ends. If any of the operations can be done in either order, say so. Justify your order. Below is the order I came up with from my readings but I can't really find any reasonable justifications for my response.

1. restore the data register values
2. restore the stack pointer to point to the user stack
3. restore the interrupt vector
4. restore the interrupt mask
5. restore the status register
6. restore the instruction register to the user program

Comment: Can other processes run while the interrupt is being handled? If so, maybe can you think of this as a concurency problem. What happens if another process attempts to access the same data as the interrupted one? What if another interrupt is raised while you're still handling this one?

Comment: It's in a general case, I'm only just starting to learn this stuff so we are only concerned with the bare bones.

Comment: Presumably you do have some justification for some of the orderring for your list (6 being the most obvious).  What is the interrupt handler doing with the interrupt vector, that it needs to restore it? Think about where the items being restored are being restored from (register, status, interrupt vector) if they're on the stack they need restored before the stack is put back.  Also think about the impact that restoring things like the interrupt mask/vector + status registers will have on what can happen next.